# add to cart button on featured products is not working

Tags: addtocart, featured-product

please visit this link : on home page, "add to cart button" on featured products is not working.

Comment: How to build an add to cart button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23005480/1480397

Comment: i will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the button you cart button did not `have addtocart link.`. so it issue

you want `addtocart url of a product then` you below code

```
Mage::helper(checkout/cart)->getAddUrl($productOjebect,$additional = array());
```

and then

line near 74: change

```
<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo  Mage::helper(checkout/cart)->getAddUrl($_product,$additional = array()); ?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your help. can you please tell me, where i have to add above code? in which file, i have featured_grid.phtml and featured_list.phtml in public_html/app/design/frontend/default/galaelectronues/template/em_featured_products. thanks in advance

Comment: put featured_list.phtml  and featured_grid.phtml on question

Comment: hi, featured_grid.phtml => http://pastebin.com/HQXN2ZbJ

Comment: hi, featured_list.phtml = > please tell me on which line number i have to place the code....

Comment: check this.......

Comment: i am working on it.

Comment: as internet is not working here, please wait for some time, i will surelay accept your answer, sorry for the delay

Comment: hi, please visit this links , http://www.themaorishop.co.nz

http://www.themaorishop.co.nz/cremes.html
 if i change in featured products related css, categories pages css is altering, and viceversa. i am really in big trouble now. please give me some solution.

Comment: i am really sorry to inform , i did changes as you told,after  home page was disappered. nothing was displayed. so I re changed the code to original code. can you please tell me, is there anything else i have to do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have Found that all your all code is working fine

The Problem is CSS because you design is not good.

please check my image and remove the `Position: relative;` from `.products-grid .price-box`

Refresh your cache and Enjoy.

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your reply, i will check and reply soon....

Comment: hi, please visit this links , http://www.themaorishop.co.nz

http://www.themaorishop.co.nz/cremes.html
 you are right, if i change in featured products related css, categories pages css is altering, and viceversa. i am really in big trouble now. please give me some solution.

Comment: check theme style.css and solve follow the above steps

Comment: your developer has changes some css so this issue arise

Comment: please visit both links and hover on product names, and change left:15px; if i change left in home page, http://www.themaorishop.co.nz/cremes.html this page name is moving.

Comment: i found you have put add to cart button before price

Comment: please visit both links and hover on product names, and change left:15px;


in theme.css 308, grid .product-name a { position :relative; left:15px; }

if i change the left:15 to Left:40; http://www.themaorishop.co.nz
 link will work, but http://www.themaorishop.co.nz/cremes.html will not work

Comment: you are right, in theme before only "add to cart button was there before price.

Comment: yes then solve that problem

Comment: okay, i will try, please be with me for some time.

Comment: please give me some time brother.... i will check with the add to cart button on featured products....

Comment: ok sure :)............

Comment: i did this now, after this if i click "add to cart", it's linking to the Products display page.

it's not adding the product to cart. please give me some solution for this....

Comment: becuase you have custom option if the product has no custom option then It will directly add to in cart

Comment: now, what's the solution for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16938/discussion-between-keyul-shah-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: this is as per magento Standard

Comment: please put comments here : i don't know to chat here.

Comment: this functionality is as per Magento Standard

Comment: is i have to login again for this?

Comment: okay, i will try , send me a message in chat....

Comment: ok no problem...........

Comment: hi, i have problem brother, you don't have problem na, you are spending your time to helping me to solve my problem.

Comment: I am busy with work right now

Comment: okay, that's fine, i don't want to disturb you now. please help me later.

Comment: thanks but don't do now again today.otherwise it will block us

Comment: oh ,okay sure. thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys i saw your site is looking good.I find the solution to you problem.just css error  instead core code change

.products-grid .btn-cart{
 remove the  (float:right)
}

then it will work .............

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, can you please tell me on which line it is there, because i could't able to find thst code. thanks in adavcne.